# Extract subsets of a data frame based on a proportion of the total number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset a data frame into a number of equal subsets that are based on a proportion of the total number of rows in the data frame. Given a data frame containing 30 rows (see simple example data below), I would like to end up with 10 subsets of data each three rows long. The first subset would contain rows 1:3 (the first 10% of rows), the second subset would contain rows 4:6 (10% – 20%) and so on until 100%.

Example data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(datetime = c("05/04/2012 14:56", "05/04/2012 14:57", 
"05/04/2012 14:58", "05/04/2012 14:59", "05/04/2012 15:00", "05/04/2012 15:01", 
"05/04/2012 15:02", "05/04/2012 15:03", "05/04/2012 15:04", "05/04/2012 15:05", 
"05/04/2012 15:06", "05/04/2012 15:07", "05/04/2012 15:08", "05/04/2012 15:09", 
"05/04/2012 15:10", "05/04/2012 15:11", "05/04/2012 15:12", "05/04/2012 15:13", 
"05/04/2012 15:14", "05/04/2012 15:15", "05/04/2012 15:16", "05/04/2012 15:17", 
"05/04/2012 15:18", "05/04/2012 15:19", "05/04/2012 15:20", "05/04/2012 15:21", 
"05/04/2012 15:22", "05/04/2012 15:23", "05/04/2012 15:24", "05/04/2012 15:25"
), count = c(23L, 56L, 45L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 19L, 28L, 24L, 17L, 
26L, 28L, 34L, 38L, 19L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 20L, 27L, 25L, 
18L, 37L, 32L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 23L), behav = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), btime = c(473.1, 473.1, 
473.1, 473.1, 473.1, 473.1, 72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 
72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 72.9, 543, 543, 543, 543, 543, 543, 543, 543, 
543, 543, 600, 600, 600, 600)), .Names = c("datetime", "count", 
"behav", "btime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
))
```

I could do this manually using something like `obj1 = df[1:3, ]`, 
`obj2 = df[4:6, ]` etc…but I am working with large data frames so I would like to find an automated way of doing this. I have managed to extract the first 10% of rows using the below code (although I am sure that there is a better way to do this), but am struggling to go on the extract the subsequent subsets.

```
obj1 = head(df[order(df$datetime),],0.1*nrow(df))
```

I would like to end up with the below:

```
> obj1
          datetime     time count behav btime
1 05/04/2012 14:56 14:56:00    23     1 473.1
2 05/04/2012 14:57 14:57:00    56     1 473.1
3 05/04/2012 14:58 14:58:00    45     2 473.1

> obj2
          datetime     time count behav btime
4 05/04/2012 14:59 14:59:00    33     2 473.1
5 05/04/2012 15:00 15:00:00    34     2 473.1
6 05/04/2012 15:01 15:01:00    33     3 473.1

etc…to obj10
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut` to create a grouping variable, `grp`, and then split `df` on that.  This gives a list, `obj`, such that `obj[[1]]` is the first group, etc.

```
grp <- cut(1:nrow(df), 10, labels = FALSE)
obj <- split(df, grp)
```

I don't recommend creating 10 separate variables out of that but to do that anyways:

```
names(obj) <- paste0("obj", names(obj))
attach(obj)
```

would attach a namespace to the path containing them or the following would create such variables right in the workspace:

```
names(obj) <- paste0("obj", names(obj))
for(g in names(obj)) assign(g, obj[[g]])
```

**REVISED**  Improved names.

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck: this is amazing! Just what I was looking for. Thank you so much.